# How to stop Visual Studio from putting 'mdd' at the end of library names

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I use Visual Studio 2013 to make a CLR-compatible version of my C++ code library ('mylibrary.lib').  It's been working fine for years, but all of a sudden I'm getting 'LNK1104' errors because Visual Studio is looking for 'mylibrarymdd.lib'.

Why is it suddenly, magically tacking on 'mdd' to the library name instead of using the .lib file I specified?  And how do I get it to stop doing this?

Comment: Have you recently added one or more build configurations? `/MDd` is the switch for multi-threaded dynamic debug build. I have seen similar added to build outputs to distinguish their build type(s).

Comment: Nope. Source code changes only. Under what conditions to VS normally do this?

Comment: It doesn't do it automatically, but the output target name can be set in one of the project properties screens.

Comment: While i could change the output target name of my dependency library to match what VS is expecting, I'd prefer to be able to name libraries as i see fit and tell VS to link with what I tell it to.  That's what it was doing before with no problems.

Comment: My top-level project which uses the dependency spits out two .lib files of its own.  the first is /MT for C++ and the second is /MD for .net consumption.  Two different project files.  Interestingly, the C++ /MT project does NOT assume 'mt' or 'mtd' is on the end of the dependency name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two workarounds for this problem, but don't like either one of them.  Hopefully someone is able to explain why these steps were unnecessary and then all of a sudden necessary.

The first and most obvious work-around is to modify the dependency's project settings so the target output filename matches what the consuming project is expecting -- namely, 'mylibrarymdd.lib'.

The second work-around is to use "/NODEFAULTLIB:mylibrarymdd.lib".  This is required for every individual dependency with the auto-naming issue.

To get to the correct (IMHO) solution, one would need to know WHY Visual Studio is creating a "default library dependency" of 'mylibraryMDD.lib' in the first place.  As I stated, it wasn't doing so before and there have been no recent updates to Visual Studio or the project files themselves.

I did find that there was a change to a dependency of 'mylibrary'.  It pulls in the static OpenSSL libraries and those were updated.  It's unclear how that would cause the above behavior, however.